# Find original content author from a re-posted video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Here's the same video, under two different channels:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYh9DCN8ads
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_v7QrIW0zY

The second one is the original I believe.  But if you query the api using the id 'gYh9DCN8ads', it seems like there's no information that points you to the original content creator, is there?  All you can get is the channel, which is FlorianPurcarus, not Isaac Lamb.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to get the original video ID since YouTube does not make this information available to the public.

However, if you are the owner of the content and you are a [Content ID](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797370?hl=en) partner, you are able to list active claims on one of your assets. For more information about that, please reach out to your Partner Technology Manager for more information.

Comment: There's start-up https://Pexe.so/ which tracks duplicate videos across the Internet. Probably, they have some API you can use.